# SQL subtract two columns giving error- Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals subtract, type equals nvarchar

Tags: t-sql, windows-xp, windows-embedded

I am trying to subtract 2 columns in a database table and call the column calc, and its giving me an error:

*Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals subtract, type equals nvarchar.*

Anyone shed some light on this? Thanks.

```
SELECT  
      ,[old]
      ,[new]
       , (new - old) as calc
    FROM database
```

database:

[image: data]

what i want to show with calc column:

[image]

Comment: `-` doesn't make sense on strings.  Provide sampled data and desired results.

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear to you???  You can't do `('Hello' - 'World')`.  What do you think would be the result of that?

Comment: can you help how i can convert them to numeric so?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT  
  ,[old]
  ,[new]
   , (numeric(new) - numeric(old)) as calc
FROM database
```

Comment: its giving an error: 'NUMERIC' is not a recognized function name.

Comment: What database are you using? The command will be specific to each database type (i.e. SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, MS Access...)

Comment: @user1959064 That is what you get if you don't tag your question properly with the right dbms.  Someone give you solution, but it won't work because it's for the wrong dbms system.

Comment: point taken. i will tag correctly. I am using tsql on MS windows embedded standard xp